# How do messages recordings for mobile phones work?

Tags: wireless-networking, android

When I call my mobile phone from my other phone, and I do not pick it up, I am prompted to leave a message. When I take out the mobile phone's battery, and I call the phone, it does not ring. However, I am still prompted with a message. I can still record that message.

The question is, where am I recording that message to? An hour passes, another one. Finally I decide to put the battery back into the mobile phone and turn it on. When the phone booted up, I am informed that the phone has a new message, and I indeed hear the message that I recorded when that phone was power off. Where did that message come from? I suppose that immediately when the phone turned on, it got that message wirelessly from external source? What external source is this?

Do messages get sent to the phone directly, or do they get sent to some kind of central computer first, and then to the destination phone? If I send a message to a phone that is power down, does the message go to this hypothetical computer and gets stored there? If this is true, then which computer is this and who manages it? The phone service company, or maybe someone else? Can they read and access my messages? If I never turn on that mobile phone again, do the messages stay indefinitely on that computer? And how does the algorithm know where to send the message to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, recorded voice mail is not stored on the phone.  It is stored by your wireless provider, on their servers.  This allows you to access your voicemail from any phone by calling your number or their voice message line and entering the proper information.  This allows you to always have access to your messages, whether or not you have your phone.

Secondly, when someone calls your phone, the wireless provider checks to see if your phone is online.  If it is, the call is passed to it causing it to ring.  After a preset time and no one answers, the call is forwarded to the wireless provider voice mail service.  When your battery was removed, your phone is offline and the provider simply transfers the call directly to voice mail.

Can your wireless provider hear your messages?  Well, it depends.  Some providers encrypt your data, some might not.  Some may have the ability to decrypt it, some might not.  It depends on their methods.  However, this is a completely different and complex issue.